# Getting revert error on transfer ether to wallet address

Tags: ether, erc-20

hi i m calculate the ether value with token price and quantity of tokens and than sending calculated ether value to seller account but i am getting revert error on remix at escrow.originatorAddress.transfer(amount); this line. i have sufficient balance also. Where am i making a mistake
below is my code.

```
function buyToken(uint256 _tradeId, address token, uint256 _quantity, uint256 _tokenPrice) payable external {

      uint256 decimals = 10 ** 9;
   //uint256 quantity = _quantity * (10 ** ERC20Interface(token).decimals();

   uint256 amount = _quantity.mul(_tokenPrice);
   amount = amount.div(decimals);
  // amount = amount.div(_quantity);

   Escrow storage escrow = escrows[_tradeId];
   require (_tradeId == escrow.tradeId, "Trade not found");
   require (msg.sender != escrow.originatorAddress, "You are the owner of this sell.");  
   require(address(msg.sender).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
  // require (escrow.receivedQty > 0, "in Sufficent");
   escrow.originatorAddress.transfer(amount);

   releaseToken(_tradeId, token, escrow, _quantity);

}
```

Comment: `but i am getting revert error on remix` - pleaes find which line is causing this revert, by masking all but a single `require` statement, and repeating the process for each one of the `require` statements in your code. If none of them is causing it, then we can focus on the remaining of your code. Don't ask others to do work that should take you 2 minutes to complete but would take them an hour just to get the exact setup as yours (if they could even realize what that setup is)!

Comment: escrow.originatorAddress.transfer(amount); this line give me revert error

Comment: If `escrow.originatorAddress.transfer(amount)` fails then either `address(this).balance < amount` or `escrow.originatorAddress` is the address of a contract without a `payable` fallback function or with such function and the failure occurs in it (which means you'll need to post that function here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `escrow.originatorAddress.transfer(amount)` can revert for either one of the following reasons:

1. `address(this).balance < amount`
2. `escrow.originatorAddress` is the address of a contract without a `payable` fallback function
3. `escrow.originatorAddress` is the address of a contract with a `payable` fallback function which reverts when you execute the statement above

Note that `require(address(msg.sender).balance >= amount)` doesn't rule out reason #1, because when a function executes a `transfer` statement, ether is transferred from the contract (`this`), not from the caller of the function (`msg.sender`).

You probably want to `require(msg.value >= amount)`, which would imply that `msg.sender` has passed to the contract a sufficient amount of ether when he/she called the function (and subsequently, the contract holds a sufficient amount of ether to transfer).

For reason #3, we will need to see the code of that fallback function...

Comment: this is not contract address it is seller wallet address

Comment: @LoveChawda: Well then it has to be reason #1 in that case. Please read the note that I added about it.

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: you are right require(address(this.balance >= amount) give me error. you said ether is transferred from the contract but i want to send from buyer account. what should i do for that.

Comment: @LoveChawda: Please see my update on what you probably want to do.

Comment: i called the buy function got the value from msg.value but still contract does not have sufficient balance. how can i provide balance to contarct.

Comment: @LoveChawda: Please make sure that it is **still** the `transfer` statement which reverts, and not some other operation in your code. And please explain what you mean by "got the value from msg.value". What am I suppose to conclude from that about what you've actually changed in your code???

Comment: Thankyou so much now it is working fine.